# AngularJS: Multi column Dropdown list

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to create a dropdown list which will carry multiple columns in tabular form. Let say dropdown with columns as Id, Result, Count. It tried using ui.select options however it doesnt work well when deployed in production. Can anyone help me ? Please suggest alternatives if any.

Please find the sample code which I am referring to. and the link referred is
http://plnkr.co/edit/a3KlK8dKH3wwiiksDSn2?p=preview

```
<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="select2" ng-disabled="disabled" style="min-width: 300px;">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Select a person in the list or search his name/age...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <table style="table table-bordered" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="280px">
        <tr class="reportHeader">
<td align="left" style="width:50px">ID</td>
<td align="right" style="width:10px"></td>
<td align="left" style="width:160px">Name</td>
<td  align="right" style="width:60px">Records</td>
</tr>
</table>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="person in people | propsFilter: {name: $select.search, age: $select.search}">      
      <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" width="280px">
        <tr>
          <td align="left" style="width:100px">{{person.name}}</td>
          <td align="left" style="width:10px"></td>
          <td align="left" style="width:200px">{{person.email}}</td>
          <td align="left" style="width:10px"></td>
          <td align="left" style="width:60px"><span ng-bind-html="''+person.age | highlight: $select.search"></span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ui-select-choices>
  </ui-select>
```

Comment: Please show us your code

Comment: I have updated my questions with code section. Please advise. What I am trying to do is, replace the name,email and age with my custom fields and made necessary changes in Object call also. Still not working.

Comment: Can we acheive this using a custom directive

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work well?

Comment: Dropdown is not getting displayed, instead it shows only a label and object binding is also failing. It shows $select.placeholder in label format.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for an solution to this:

```
        <style>
        .selectedOrder {
            height: 30px; 
            display:none; 
        }

    /* class applies to select element itself, not a wrapper element */
    .select-css {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-weight: 700;
        color: #444;
        line-height: 1.3;
        padding: .6em 1.4em .5em .8em;
        /* width: 100%; */
        max-width: 100%; /* useful when width is set to anything other than 100% */
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        border: 1px solid #aaa;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,.04);
        border-radius: .5em;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        background-color: #fff;
        /* note: bg image below uses 2 urls. The first is an svg data uri for the arrow icon, and the second is the gradient. 
            for the icon, if you want to change the color, be sure to use `%23` instead of `#`, since it's a url. You can also swap in a different svg icon or an external image reference
            
        */
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22%23007CB2%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
          linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
        background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
        /* arrow icon position (1em from the right, 50% vertical) , then gradient position*/
        background-position: right .7em top 50%, 0 0;
        /* icon size, then gradient */
        background-size: .65em auto, 100%;
    }
    /* Hide arrow icon in IE browsers */
    .select-css::-ms-expand {
        display: none;
    }
    /* Hover style */
    .select-css:hover {
        border-color: #888;
    }
    /* Focus style */
    .select-css:focus {
        border-color: #aaa;
        /* It'd be nice to use -webkit-focus-ring-color here but it doesn't work on box-shadow */
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px rgba(59, 153, 252, .7);
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px -moz-mac-focusring;
        color: #222; 
        outline: none;
    }

    /* Set options to normal weight */
    .select-css option {
        font-weight:normal;
    }

    /* Support for rtl text, explicit support for Arabic and Hebrew */
    *[dir="rtl"] .select-css, :root:lang(ar) .select-css, :root:lang(iw) .select-css {
        background-position: left .7em top 50%, 0 0;
        padding: .6em .8em .5em 1.4em;
    }

    /* Disabled styles */
    .select-css:disabled, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
        color: graytext;
        background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=US-ASCII,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20width%3D%22292.4%22%20height%3D%22292.4%22%3E%3Cpath%20fill%3D%22graytext%22%20d%3D%22M287%2069.4a17.6%2017.6%200%200%200-13-5.4H18.4c-5%200-9.3%201.8-12.9%205.4A17.6%2017.6%200%200%200%200%2082.2c0%205%201.8%209.3%205.4%2012.9l128%20127.9c3.6%203.6%207.8%205.4%2012.8%205.4s9.2-1.8%2012.8-5.4L287%2095c3.5-3.5%205.4-7.8%205.4-12.8%200-5-1.9-9.2-5.5-12.8z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E'),
          linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff 0%,#e5e5e5 100%);
    }

    .select-css:disabled:hover, .select-css[aria-disabled=true] {
        border-color: #aaa;
    }
</style>

<div id="orderSelectContainer">
    <div id="selectedOrder" class="selectedOrder select-css" style="width: 533px; display: block;">
        <div class="currentSelectedOrder" data-value="45628" style="float: left;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 1</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55628</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="orderSelect" class="select-css" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1000; background-image: none; display: none;">
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45628" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 1</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55628</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45536" style="float: left; background: lightblue;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 2</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55536</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45682" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 3</span><span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55682</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45625" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 4</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55625</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px">  </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="orderContainer">
            <div class="order" data-value="45556" style="float: left; background: white;">
                <span style="float:left; min-width:200px;">Store 5</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:50px"> 55556</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width: 150px;"> Quantity Discrepancy</span>
                <span style="float:left; min-width:100px"> Bad UPCs</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both"><br>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).on(`click`, `.order`, function() {
        if ($(this).data(`value`) !== $(`#selectedOrder >.currentSelectedOrder`).data(`value`)) {
            $(`#orderContainer`).html(``);
        }
        $(`#selectedOrder`).html($(this).prop(`outerHTML`)).find(`.order`).removeClass(`order`).css(`background`, ``).addClass(`currentSelectedOrder`);
        $(`.order`).css(`background`, `white`);
        $(this).css(`background`, `lightblue`);
        $(`#selectedOrder`).show();
        $(`#orderSelect`).hide();
    });

    $(document).on(`click`, `#selectedOrder`, function() {
        //$(`#selectedOrder`).hide();
        $(`#orderSelect`).toggle();
    });

    $(document).on(`mouseenter`, `.order`, function() {
        $(`.order`).css(`background`, `white`);
        $(this).css(`background`, `lightblue`);
    });

    $(document).on(`mouseexit`, `.order`, function() {
        $(this).css(`background`, `white`);
    });
<script>
```

working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/schmidtc63/xu8zgpc9/